# How to create a class from another inaccessible package

Tags: java

I have this class in Package A:

```
public class PortletClickHandler implements CustomClickHandler {

        private int portletId;

        public int getPortletId() {
            return portletId;
        }

        public void setPortletId(int portletId) {
            this.portletId = portletId;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
            logger.info("Entering here");
            logger.info(String.valueOf(portletId));

            setContextArea(portletId);
            logger.info("Class is ");
            logger.info("Does it work?");

        }

    }
```

I also have the below code

```
Content = new HomePage(new PortletClickHandler());
```

where I will be using it at another package B via interface:

```
public interface CustomClickHandler extends ClickHandler {
        void setPortletId(int portletId);
    }
```

My issue right now is as Package A will have the import from Package B(Where HomePage is) such that:

```
import package B.HomePage
```

But I cant do the another way around where Package B imports the Package A as it will cause the circular dependency.

Below is the error message:

```
Adding dependency on module 'A' will introduce circular dependency between modules 'B' and 'C'. Add dependency anyway?
```

Therefore, when I would like to create a new instance of PortletClickHandler class at Package B, I am unable to do so.

Eg: `PortletClickHandler handler = new PortletClickHandler();`. When I do this in the package B, it will ask me to import the this PortletClickHandler, but when I selects to import this, it will then cause the circular depedency message.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `it will cause the dependency loop.` Are you sure?  Did you try it? I don't think dependency loops are a thing in Java.  Try it, please tell us the full error message you get.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the changes that I made

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.  Can you post code that reproduces the problem?

Working:

```
package stackoverflow.pakA;
import stackoverflow.pakB.ClassB;

public class MainA {
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      ClassB.methodB();
   }
   
   public static void methodA() {
      System.out.println( "Hellow from method A" );
   }
}

package stackoverflow.pakB;
import stackoverflow.pakA.MainA;

public class ClassB {
   
   public static void methodB() {
      System.out.println( "Hello from method B" );
      MainA.methodA();
   }
   
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Hello from method B
Hellow from method A
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Hi, the code that is causing the problem is 'PortletClickHandler handler = new PortletClickHandler();'. 
You can refer to the edit that I made

Comment: Can you produce a complete compilable example that reproduces the problem? [mcve]